# Blackberry programming - Timer class

Tags: java, blackberry, timer, real-time

The BlackBerry API documentation for the [Timer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html) class says:

> This class does not offer real-time guarantees: it schedules tasks using the Object.wait(long) method.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means when you schedule a timer task, the task will start executing no sooner than the requested start time, but could start later, and the amount of time later has no bound.

A real-time guarantee would give a bound on the maximum amount of time that elapses before execution starts.